# Cant create console app

Tags: console

So i'm following a tutorial to connect Toky with Salesforce and a console application is needed, but i can't seem to create one.
I've checked and I have a sales console user licence unused.
[image]

So, when creating a new app I should see a window like this:
[image]

But it actually takes me straight to naming the app.

Another thing that I noticed is that on the app views there should be a column indicating if an app is a console app, like this: 
[image]
But on my view that column doesn't shows up.

Any idea on what could be wrong? Maybe there is something I need to activate.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to create a custom service cloud console in classic, or a "console app" in Lightning Experience?

Answer (score 0):

Taking everything at face value and that you are trying to do this with a Classic console, and after playing with it a bit, what I've found is that unless my user record has `Service Cloud User` checked, I do not get the option to create console-type apps in the Classic UI.

This conforms to Salesforce [help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_define_app.htm&type=5) which states that you can only create a console if you either have the `Service Cloud User` permission or the `Sales Console` permission (as well as the standard `View Setup and Configuration` and `Customize Application` perms you would normally need to use Setup).

My (very old) DE org has a standard permission set called **Saleforce Console User** which can be assigned to yourself to enable the `Sales Console` user perm.

[image: Salesforce Console Permission Set]

Your user record is where you find the tickbox to assign yourself the `Service Cloud User` permission.

[image: Service Cloud User]

Indeed, the fact that you have the *unallocated* permission in your screen shot verifies that the org you are working with has no users enabled for Sales Console (therefore no one who can create a console). Once you assign the permission to yourself, you should see the *Used Licenses* (Licencias Utilizadas) column value go to 1 to indicate it is in use.